# W3C error on WordPress site: attributes src-large, src-full, src-medium "not allowed on element img at this point"

Tags: html, wordpress, image, w3c-validation

I'm getting a lot of error in W3C. One of them is:

> Attribute `src-large` not allowed on element `img` at this point.

The same error is given for attribute `src-full` and `src-medium`.

How can I remove this attribute? And very important, where?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean using validator.w3.org to validate your code - if so, I wish there were more web-devs like you.
Please include an example and context for more detail.

Comment: There are, I too validate my sites' code (although I must admit I don't do it as often now as when I first started developing websites).

Comment: Laurene, don't remove these attributes. Instead, follow the suggestions made on Dragonthoughts' answer and you won't break any existing functionality on your site.

Answer (score 1):

The errors show because they are not HTML standard attributes.

Depending on your exact usages, you may be able to either replace them using the `srcset` attribute on the `<img>` or replace the `<img>` elements with `<picture>` elements.

see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp
and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp
for finer detail

Comment: ... or convert these attributes into [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and the errors will go away: `data-src-full`, `data-src-medium` (but of course she'll also need to change the code that relies on that so that images are correctly displayed afterwards).

Comment: Thank for your answer, so I'll replace it by a srcset but as a beginner I have bo idea on how I can replace it.